# MATLAB structure arrays, mex, and memory

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm a little lost in finding the mex analagous concept to this m-code snippet:

```
a.one = linspace(1,100);
a.two = linspace(101,200);
a.three = linspace(201,300);

for it = 1:100
    b(it).one = it;
    b(it).two = it+100;
    b(it).three = it+200;
end
```

Running the above m-code produces two structures each with the same content:

```
>> a

a = 

  struct with fields:

      one: [1×100 double]
      two: [1×100 double]
    three: [1×100 double]

>> b

b = 

  1×100 struct array with fields:

    one
    two
    three
```

but vastly different memory consumption:

```
>> whos
  Name      Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         1x1               2928  struct              
  b         1x100            36192  struct
```

I'm in the process of learning the depths of mex functions, data types, etc. and can't figure out the equivalent mex implementation to recreating 'a' and 'b' within a mex function and returning them to the MATLAB workspace. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Running the above m-code produces two structures each with the **same** content". But they are not. You just illustrated how each element of a `struct` array seems to have its own memory allocation. Good job!

Comment: they are different. a is 1x1 struct with 3 arrays, b is a 1x100 struct with 3 arrays each

Comment: yes, that's true. I acknowledged exactly this, its actually the fundamental basis for my question. My question is how to replicate such similar but fundamentally different structures from mex. Any suggestions, or just sarcasm to offer @Argyll ?

Comment: To clarify the obvious, they are the same in regard to the amount of data they store, but not in regard to their memory footprint. In Mathworks' own words "Even though S1 and S2 contain the same amount of data [...]" from https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/memory-allocation.html#brh72ex-14 look for S1 and S2 comparison. I presume you know this, but can't be bothered to offer a solution to recreating 'a' and 'b' structures in mex. thanks.

Comment: Sarcasm? I would suggest editing in what you just told me in your question to make it clearer. And to be honest, even then I am still not sure what you are asking. The ways matlab manages memory are proprietary and quite tricky to pinpoint.

Comment: I formatted my quandary not in a question, but a statement of where I'm stuck. Maybe a few question marks as in Spanish language would help identify the question. ¿How can I figure out the equivalent mex implementation to recreating 'a' and 'b' within a mex function and returning them to the MATLAB workspace?

Comment: When you say "mex implementation", do you mean you want to create your own array instances and control how they are implemented in memory with C? I tried to find an article from a few years ago that describes some of the tests the OP and others performed to explore how matlab implements matrices in memory. I can't find it anymore. In short, it's elaborate and one can only gain circumstantial knowledge of its methods. Try `format debug` if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a MEX-file, the function [`mxCreateStructMatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatestructmatrix.html) is used to create the struct matrix, and [`mxSetField`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxsetfield.html) to assign arrays into it.

To replicate your M-file code in a C MEX-file you'd do something like this:

```c
// Define field names
const char* fieldNames[] = {"one", "two", "three"};

// a: scalar struct with matrix elements
mxArray* a = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, 3, fieldNames);
mxArray* elem = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 100, mxREAL);
// fill `elem` with values 1-100
mxSetField(a, 0, fieldNames[0], elem);
elem = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 100, mxREAL);
// fill `elem` with values 101-200
mxSetField(a, 0, fieldNames[1], elem);
elem = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 100, mxREAL);
// fill `elem` with values 201-300
mxSetField(a, 0, fieldNames[2], elem);

// b: matrix struct with scalar elements
mxArray* b = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 100, 3, fieldNames);
for (int it=1; it != 101; ++it) {
   mxSetField(b, it, fieldNames[0], mxCreateDoubleScalar(it));
   mxSetField(b, it, fieldNames[1], mxCreateDoubleScalar(it+100));
   mxSetField(b, it, fieldNames[2], mxCreateDoubleScalar(it+200));
}
```

I've left out the code to fill the `elem` matrices with values, it involves using `mxGetPr` function to retrieve the pointer to the first element, and writing into that array.

Comment: Thanks, Cris. Exactly what I was looking for. Very clear.